# Console output of a program including redirected stdin?

Tags: bash, stdin, io-redirection

I have a command line program that I'm passing redirected input to, and piping to a file:

```
./program < some_input_file > some_output_file
```

This obviously writes the output not including the redirected input. Is there some simple way to get a log of the program, **including** the redirected input that I've passed in?

I'm open to using an external program or script - I'm running this on bash/linux.

[EDIT]

I'm looking for a way to get the output interleaved - as if the program was run in a terminal, with the input file just typed in manually

Comment: You can always `cat input > output; ./program < input >> output` but is this what you want?

Comment: See my response below for serial and parallel combinations

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of how you can do it:

```
> cat input.txt
asdf
qwer
zxcv
> tee output.txt < input.txt | cat >> output.txt 
> cat output.txt
asdf
qwer
zxcv
asdf
qwer
zxcv
```

Just replace `cat` in the above with your program and you should be good.  Now if you want it interleaved then you have to do something different:

```
> while read line
  do
      echo $line >> output.txt
      echo $line | cat >> output.txt
  done < 'input.txt'
> cat output.txt
asdf
asdf
qwer
qwer
zxcv
zxcv
```

again replacing `cat` with your shell script.

Comment: You'll also need to make sure that your program `cat` also flushes its output buffer at every write (or at a minimum, every read from stdin).

Comment: Doesn't this require the program cat to finish before we enter the next iteration of the loop? In other words, this will run cat once for each line in my input file?

Comment: @andy @thekidder Couple things here.  I have no idea about what program is here.  It is a black box but to the original question I did provide examples showing how to produce the desired output in serial and parallel.  If you want something that is more efficient then I would consider using threads in your program to solve this problem rather than just relying on facilities provided by the shell.

Comment: Your "interleaved" example can only work if calling the OP's "command line program" repeatedly for each input line produces the same result as calling it only once with the whole input; the OP did not specify this restriction.

Answer (score 1):

If your program prints some kind of prompt before reading its next input, you can use `expect` to interact with it. Your `expect` script can print each input line as it's read and send it to the program once it sees the prompt. That gives you correct, interleaved output without running your program once per line.